# Cannot print array in the hash of another array

Tags: perl

Please check the following code. I want to print array, but it only print the first item in array.

```
$prefix = 'ABC';
$search_pc_exclude = "PC1 PC2 PC3";

@exclude = split(/\s+/, $search_pc_exclude);
push @prefix, {"pre" => $prefix, "exc" => @exclude};

print $prefix[0]->{pre};
print $prefix[0]->{exc}; #why this is not array?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment actually is processed like this:

```
push @prefix, {"pre" => $prefix, "exc" => "PC1", "PC2" => "PC"}
```

Which gives you a hash with these keys. You need an array reference for that:

```
# This creates a copy of @exclude
push @prefix, {"pre" => $prefix, "exc" => [@exclude]}
```

Or:

```
# This creates a reference to @exclude. Any modifications to
# $prefix[0]->{exc} are actually modifications to @exclude
push @prefix, {"pre" => $prefix, "exc" => \@exclude}
```

Comment: Thanks Linus! But after changing it to \@exclude, I still could not print it (print $prefix[0]->{exc};), but got "ARRAY(0x9e2b368)".

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I need to dereference it first (ie, $arr = $prefix[0]->{exc}; @arr = @$arr;) Thanks again!

Comment: That's because $prefix[0]->{exc} is an array reference, which you need to dereference! Use print @{ prefix[0]->{exc} } to print the array...